# throw new Error('no parsers registered for: "' + self.input.slice(0, 5) + '"'); Live-server NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, npm-live-server

I'm on Kali Linux 2019.1, and here's my modules and scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build-task:scss-compile": "node-sass-chokidar --source-map true sass/main.scss  css/style.css",
    "build-task:autoprefixer": "postcss css/*.css --use autoprefixer -d css",
    "sass:build": "npm-run-all -p build-task:*",
    "sass:watch": "chokidar 'sass/**/*.scss' -c 'npm run sass:build'",
    "dev": "npm-run-all -p sass:*"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {},
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.10",
    "chokidar-cli": "^1.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2"
}
```

So I've installed `live-server` with npm and when I'm trying to run it

Here's the error

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/parser.js:473
        throw new Error('no parsers registered for: "' + self.input.slice(0, 5) + '"'); 
        ^ 

Error: no parsers registered for: "]"
    at parse (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/parser.js:473:15)
    at Parser.parse (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/parser.js:477:24)
    at Snapdragon.parse (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/snapdragon/index.js:122:28)
    at Snapdragon.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:40:45)
    at Braces.parse (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:66:26)
    at Braces.expand (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:87:18)
    at create (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/index.js:142:15)
    at memoize (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/index.js:298:13)
    at Function.braces.create (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/index.js:165:10)
    at Function.braces.expand (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/live-server/node_modules/braces/index.js:81:17)
```

Here's my versions of Node NPM and live-server.

`node version : v10.15.1`

`npm version : 6.8.0`

`live-server version : 1.2.1`

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: can you add more information?
why dont you have the live-server on package.json deps?

Comment: https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1622

maybe this is not a live-server issue but a dep issue.
the same happens on other packages.

Comment: I installed it with the flag -g that's why, what is a dep ? Thanks for helping me

Comment: dep is dependency :) @hatim-naíìmi

Comment: I installed live-server with the -g flag

Comment: I found my mistake, I didn't run it with arguments how can I close the subject, btw Thanks for your help @Vetras